# Why does my SearchView disappear when it gets focus?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, searchview

I have an `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` inside of an `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and it looks fine in the Android Studio designer preview and also when I first launch the app. As soon as I touch on the SearchView, however, it disappears. Closing the keyboard or focusing something else does not make it reappear.

I've played around with some different layouts as wrappers and I've come to the conclusion that it no longer takes up space in the layout (so it's more like it becomes `GONE` vs `INVISIBLE`). I've also tried attaching a `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` and this revealed that the `SearchView` is focused and its text is changing as I type- even if it's not visible.

Any ideas what might be going on here or how I could debug it? Googling the problem doesn't really turn up anything relevant and I'm all out of ideas.

If it's any help, the layout code follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.me.MyActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/internalSearchView"
                    app:queryHint="To..."
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: When you say that you tried using `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`, you were able to type in the place of the `SearchView` which was invisible and yet you were able to detect the text ?

Comment: @San Yes, exactly. The query text was updating as I would expect if everything was acting normally.

Comment: I have the same problem.